# /testfor @p[score_state=1,score_state_min=1] doesn't work!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/testfor @p[score_state=1,score_state_min=1]
```

doesn't work! Why?

It returns this:

> The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error simply means no targets were found, meaning there was not a living player with a "state" score of 1. You must set their score first:

```
/scoreboard players set @p state 1
```